# How to open an notepad for every 2 minutes using Windows scheduler in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, taskservice

I have the following code for opening notepad for every 1 minutes. But it is not working. Can somebody suggest me the answer?

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "My first task scheduler";

    TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger();
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    td.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"D:\Tasks\sample.exe", null, null));
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("TaskName", td);
}
```

Comment: Does this executable "D:\Tasks\sample.exe" open notepad.exe?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the System.Diagnostics.Process class to open Notepad: -

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
proc.Start();
```

It can also open a particular file in the ProcesStartInfo as: -

```
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", "C://temp/log.txt");
```

Comment: I need the .exe to be opened for every 2 minutes.

Comment: Please clarify... do you need the 'notepad.exe' to be opened, then wait for 2 mins and then closed?